# how can i assign each file name in global array?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use multiple file upload and I want to assign each file name with the global array called `img` using the foreach how can I do it in asp.net/c#?

```
string[] img={""};

foreach (string s in Request.Files) {
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];
    int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
    string fileName = file.FileName;
    string fileExtension = "";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) {
        fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        file.SaveAs(filename);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `List<string>` for this purpose:

```
List<string> img = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];
    int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
    string fileName = file.FileName;
    string fileExtension = "";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
    {
        img.add(fileName);
        fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        file.SaveAs(filename);
    }
```

Here is a great explanation on why `List<T>` is almost always better than using an `array` in C#:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/221897

If you give us a little better explanation of what you're trying to accomplish, I could probably improve on this answer.

Comment: thank you, i have a table of items contain img1,img2,img3 and img4 i want to insert the paths of images into those columns img1,img2,etc using linq to sql so i decided to assign each path in array and then assign the array index with the linq

Comment: You can get an item by index in a List<T> the same way you can in an array.  Just simply use:  int myFirstImg = img[0];

Comment: thanks, but when int myFirstImg  = img[0]; it show this error System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: That's because you're referencing an index that doesn't exist.  Just check that it exists or that img.Count > 0 (or whatever number you need).